# How to "forward" email from one pc to another?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, email, proxy

I have two computer, one Linux and the other Windows XP. Usually I work with Linux machine, receiving email etc. Recently, my company blocked Linux pc's network, I can't recevice email as usual. However, Windows PC is allowed to access network, and the network connection between the two computer is fine. I setup a squid service on Windows pc, so I can still access website as usual with my Linux box. But squid doesn't support POP3 and SMTP.

Here comes the question, I wonder if I can setup an email exchange server on my Windows PC, forward email to my Linux box. My email server use **POP3** and **SMTP** protocal, POP3 require **SSL** autheration.

Comment: This is an attempt at a technical solution to a non technical problem. If the company blocked the GNU/Linux PC then they did that for a reason and you need to find out why, so you can convince them it is not a problem. Working around it might be a challenge (I presonally I would consider it fun to do so) but is probably not the right solution.

Comment: I can't convince them :) It's headquarter's decision, our company can do nothing. It's okey to receive email on my linux box, but i have to solve this problem.

Comment: if you use outlook on windows, you would probably be able to set up auto forward from outlook..

btw, how exactly has you company blocked specifically linux machines from accessing emails?

Comment: Nginx can proxy POP3, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Does auto-forward work? I'm not trying forward email from one account to another. I need something like MTA.

Comment: On windows PC, all the data were encrypted and sent out, the ISP will decode this encrypted data, then transfer it to internet. However, linux box lacks of such a software.

Comment: Nginx is fine, But i can't setup a webserver on my windows. Windows is totally under monitor :(

Comment: Be warned - working around company security policies can result in being let go.  You may not understand it, but these kinds of restrictions suck to implement and so aren't usually done unless necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like network traffic originating from your Windows PC is allowed (this is what is happening with squid). So instead of handeling the email on the PC you could also install a port forwarder for windows on the Windows PC. On the linux machine configure the email client to connect to the Windows Machine on port x for pop3 and port y for smtp. Port x redirects to the mail server on port 110 and port y redirects to the mail server on port 25.

Comment: thanks a lot. Should i need a mail fetcher on windows? or just forward  pop3 and smtp port to linux? anthother question, my mail server require SSL, will this solution work?